# OneDrive options showing up again out of the blue

Tags: onedrive

Windows 10 machine

I disabled/removed OneDrive upon getting the computer some years ago. Now when I'm trying to save a MS Word doc, there's a OneDrive option and showing my email address.

I do not want to see this option. How do I make it go away?

Additionally, how can I make sure something isn't happening in some mysterious OneDrive place online with my email address?

Troubleshooting so far:
In Add or Remove Programs, there is no MS OneDrive listed.
When bring up the Start menu and type OneDrive, it shows up, but when I click on it, nothing happens.

ETA clarification: I'm using Word (Office) 2003. When I installed it years ago, I managed to unlink/disable onedrive. Now it's back and I want it gone again.

Comment: Have you tried to "Unlink Onedrive" https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Turn-off-disable-or-uninstall-OneDrive-f32a17ce-3336-40fe-9c38-6efb09f944b0

Comment: "Now when I'm trying to save a MS Word doc, there's a OneDrive option and showing my email address." - This is a feature of Office 2016+ and Office 365 and would be there regardless of the version of Windows you had installed.

Comment: @vssher: Yes, but the starting conditions it describes don't correspond to anything I see on my computer so can't do the steps described.

Comment: @Ramhound: see OP for clarification.